# For an inductive limit $X = \bigcup X_n$ of vector spaces, show that $X$ is complete if $X_n$ is complete for all $n$

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a vector space. Suppose that $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of vector subspaces such that

1. $X_n \subseteq X_{n+1}$ for all $n$,
2. Each $X_n$ is a locally convex topological vector space, and the topology on $X_n$ coincides exactly with the subspace topology that it inherits for $X_{n+1}$.

Then we can definie the so-called **inductive limit topology** on $X$, which is the strongest locally convex, topological vector space topology for which the injections $X_n \to X$ are all continuous.

> I would like to prove that if $X_n$ is complete for all $n$, then $X$ is complete.

This fact is stated in Reed and Simon's *[Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics, Vol.1](http://books.google.com/books/about/Methods_of_Modern_Mathematical_Physics_F.html?id=fXX0j4qa8G8C)*. Reed and Simon give a reference for the proof: A. and W. Robertson's *[Topological Vector Spaces](http://books.google.com/books?id=mV44AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=a%20and%20w%20robertson%20topological%20vector%20spaces&source=bl&ots=H58U0ThNnl&sig=DXoLOTqtbm3LGQ7RNePURWEfKGE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7zDZU_-hD9afyATwlYHwBg&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=a%20and%20w%20robertson%20topological%20vector%20spaces&f=false).* Unfortunately, this text is not available at my University library.

Here's what I have so far. Suppose that $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy in $X$. First of all, consider the case when there exists some index $N$ so that $X_N \cap \{x_n\}$ is infinite. Then we can choose some subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ so that$\{x_{n_k}\} \subseteq X_N$. Next, Let $U$ be an arbitrary balanced, convex, basis-neighborhood of $0$ in $X_N$. Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867529/how-to-construct-a-particular-convex-set-when-defining-inductive-limits-of-frec) lemma, it is possible to lift $U$ to a balanced, convex neighborhood $\tilde{U}$ of $0$ in $X$, with the property that $X_N \cap\tilde{U} = U$. Because $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $X$, there is an $M \in \mathbb{N}$ so that

$$n,m \ge M \implies x_n -x_m \in \tilde{U}.$$

This in turn implies that

$$k,j \ge M \implies x_{n_k} -x_{n_j} \in \tilde{U} \cap X_N = U.$$

Therefore $\{x_{n_k}\}$ is Cauchy in $X_N$. By the completeness of $X_N$, there exists some $x \in X_n$ so that $x_{n_k} \to x$. To finish this case, we notice that:

$$x_n - x = (x_n - x_{n_k}) + (x_{n_k} - x)$$

So if $n$ and $k$ are made large enough, $x_n - x$ will reside inside any neighborhood $U$ of $0$ (to make this last step totally clear, we do need to recall the fact that, within any open any $V$ containing zero in $X$, we can find an open neighborhood $\tilde{V}$ of $0$ so that $\tilde{V} +\tilde{V} \subseteq V$).

> I'm not sure how to complete the proof in the case where $\{x_n\} \cap X_N$ is finite for all $N$. In that case, I'm not able to extract the subsequence $x_{n_k}$, which was the key to the proof above.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The claim seems to be false. Take, for instance, $X_n = \mathbb{R}^n$. Then the inductive limit is a real vector space of countably infinite dimension, and these are never complete (regardless of the topology).

Comment: @ZhenLin---Thank you for the comment. However, I think I am a bit confused with regard to your claim. Are you saying that a real vector space $X$ of infinite dimension is never complete, regardless of the topology that we place on $X$? But what if we take the classic example of $X = L^2(\mathbb{R})$, which has infinite Fourier basis, and is complete under the norm $(\int_\mathbb{R}|f|^2dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: @ZhenLin: how do you justify that? The argument I know uses Baire's Category Theorem, which doesn't necessarily apply to all topological vector spaces.

Comment: Oh, I suppose I was thinking about Banach spaces rather than topological vector spaces in general. Still, the direct limit $\varinjlim_n \mathbb{R}^n$ has the topology induced by the obvious metric (because the inclusions are all isometries), and that is not complete.

Comment: But of course Baire's Category Theorem shows that the topology from the OP is not given by a metric.

Answer (score 2):

We will show that the second case cannot happen. If there are only finitely many $x_i$ in each $X_k$, we find subsequences $(y_i)$ of $(x_n)$ and $(Y_i)$ of $(X_n)$ (say $y_i = y_{n_i}$,  and $Y_i = X_{m_i}$), such that $y_i \in Y_{i+1}\setminus Y_i$. As $Y_i$ is complete, it is closed in $X$, so by Hahn-Banach there is an $x_i^* \in X^*$ such that $x_i^*|_{Y_i} = 0$ and $x_i^*(y_i) = i - \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} x_k^*(y_i)$. Let $x^* := \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^*$. Then, on each $Y_i$, $x^*$ is a **finite** sum of continuous linear functionals, so $x^*|_{Y_i}$ is continuous. As $X$ carries the direct limit topology, $x^*$ is continuous on $X$. A continuous linear map on locally convex spaces maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences, but $x^*(y_i) = i$. Contradiction.

So, $X$ is sequentially complete.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but could you clarify how $X_n$ being complete implies that $X_n$ is closed in $X$? I'm having trouble coming up with this argument myself. I think it would even be enough if each $X_n$ is closed in $X_{n+1}$.

Comment: Let $(x_\alpha)$ be a net in $X_n$, such that $x_\alpha \to x \in X$. As a convergent net, $(x_\alpha)$ in Cauchy in $X$ and hence (as the topology of $X$ restricts to the given one of $X_n$) in $X_n$. As $X_n$ is complete, $x_\alpha \to y \in X_n$. As $X_n$ is Hausdorff (according to Reed/Simon's definition), $x=y$.